# Config Error in Swift 4

Tags: json, swift, api

I am receiving the following error, "Value of type 'Configuration' has no member 'config'". Basically, I am trying to establish a connection to the API listed. For reference, I am running Siesta and SwiftyJSON, both of which are new to me. Any help would be great.

```
import Foundation
import Siesta
import SwiftyJSON

let Pokeapi = _Pokeapi()

class _Pokeapi: Service {
public init() {
    super.init(baseURL: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2")
    self.configure {
        $0.config.pipeline[.parsing].add(SwiftyJSONTransformer, contentTypes: ["*/json"])
        $0.config.expirationTime = 3600
    }

}
}

public let SwiftyJSONTransformer =
ResponseContentTransformer
    { JSON($0.content as AnyObject) }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the error you get is because $0 in your closure refers to a variable of type Configuration which does not have a member called config. Instead maybe you wanted to write :

```
self.configure { config in
    config.pipeline[.parsing].add(SwiftyJSONTransformer, contentTypes: ["*/json"])
    config.expirationTime = 3600
}
```

Note you that you could also do

```
self.configure {
    $0.pipeline[.parsing].add(SwiftyJSONTransformer, contentTypes: ["*/json"])
    $0.expirationTime = 3600
}
```

but it makes a better readable code if you name the closure vars